# android applinks doesn't work on every browser?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, applinks

I try to call my app on a specific url. To do that I use this intent-filter in the manifest :

```
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="${hostName}"
                android:pathPrefix="/konfirmasi-email" />
        </intent-filter>
```

this do work with Google Chrome and Samsung Internet but don't with Xiaomi's default browser

Comment: I think it is some obscure and vendor specific setting which you should look for in the Android settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in that browser... May be that browser did not allow some links to come out of the browser..

Did you tried with http scheme??

`<data android:scheme="http" android:host="${hostName}" android:pathPrefix="/konfirmasi-email" />`